# Решить проблему в задаче.

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n; double y_pred = .3, x_pred = .3, y_tek, x_tek, sum = (x_pred/(1 + abs(y_pred)));
    cout<<"Vvedite natur. n = "; cin>>n;
    cout<<"x_pred "<<x_pred<<"y_pred "<<y_pred<<"\n";
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        x_tek = 0.3*x_pred;
        cout<<"\nx_tek = "<<x_tek<<"\n";
        y_tek = x_pred + y_pred;
        cout<<"\ny_tek = "<<y_tek<<"\n";
        sum = sum + (x_tek/(1+abs(y_tek)));
        x_pred = x_tek;
        y_pred = y_tek;
        cout<<"\nsum = "<<sum;
        }
    cout<<"\nIskomaya summa = "<<sum;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Не берет модуль. Если ставлю переменные целочисленными, то не считает сумму x_tek/(1+abs(y_tek)) (от 1 до n)...Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Что означает «не берёт модуль»? Какая строка выполняется неправильно? Можете воспроизвести проблему на более короткой программе?

Comment: #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   double n;
   n = abs(n);
    cout<<n<<"\n";
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Ошибка :  call of overloaded 'abs(double&)' is ambiguous

В моей программе выполнялася неправильно строка объявления переменных (если переменные double, если делаю int, то все значения нули, т.к. даны изначально дроби меньшие единицы.) вот, я не знаю что делать. Мне нужно взять модуль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `float` и `double` — [`fabs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/). И еще: обычно правильнее [`#include <cmath>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/?kw=cmath) вместо `#include <Math.h>`.